# Python loops with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, conditional-statements

Function `f` will do needless iterations.

```
def f(array):
    for (i, row) in enumerate(array):
        for (j, value) in enumerate(row):
            if i < some_number and j > some_other_number:
                do_something
```

Is there an idiomatic way to enforce the condition in the `for` loop?

```
def f(array):
    for (i < some_number, row) in enumerate(array):
        for (j > some_other_number, value) in enumerate(row):
            do_something
```

Comment: Even if this were possible, the same iterations would be done

Comment: However since `i` is always increasing a `break` might be useful here.

Comment: Why not just use a while loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice(iterable,start,stop[,step])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=islice#itertools.islice) for that:

```
from itertools import islice

def f(array):
    for (i, row) in islice(enumerate(array),some_number):
        for (j, value) in islice(enumerate(row),some_other_number+1,None):
            # do_something
            pass
```

Given you do not need `i` and `j` in your computation (you only need them for bounds checks, you can even omit them).

```
from itertools import islice

def f(array):
    for row in islice(array,some_number):
        for value in islice(row,some_other_number+1,None):
            # do_something
            pass
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can always use `range`:

```
def f(array):
    for i in range(some_number, len(array)):
        row = array[i]
        for j in range(some_other_number, len(row)):
            value = row[j]
            # do_something
```

provided that `some_number` does not depend on `row` and `some_other_number` does not depend on `value`. Otherwise you can't really do anything.

Note that this requires both `array` and `row` objects to support `__getelement__` (e.g. when both are real list). It won't work for generators.

Comment: That will only work if `array` and `row` support `__getelement__` however. Not generators, etc. But +1 (althoug it is perhaps worth mentioning).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem True.

Answer (score 1):

You can't in-line that condition, but you can prevent the inner loop from being entered.

```
def f(array):
    for (i, row) in enumerate(array):
        if i < some_number:
            for (j, value) in enumerate(row):
                j > some_other_number:
                    do_something
```

`enumerate` does have a `start` parameter you could try